# Connection reset error when trying to login to admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I have magento 1.9 setup for my website. When i am trying to login to the admin panel after submission the page redirects to connection reset error. I have tried various solutions like removing var folder, changing varien file but nothing of it has worked.

I have tried setting up the website on a different server and it works correctly there. It seems there is some issue with the server but i am not able to pin point the issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: Are you working locally or remotely when you receive the error. What about the other server where it works? What are the differences between the two servers? Have you checked PHP versions between the two?

Comment: @MagentoAaron I am working on remote server, my local server has php version 5.5 while the live site has 5.4 php version, but it seems the issue is due to ssl as the live site has SSL while the local server does not have it. Any ideas?

Comment: @SukumarGorai  It shows default connection reset error of browser.

Comment: So the live site is working, and the local instance is not? Have you updated the secure and unsecure base_url's at `System > Configuration > Web` in the admin of the local instance? Both should be set to `http://www.yourdomain.com/` (not https).